# List of international top-level domains that allow foreign registrations

Tags: domains, domain-hacks

Wikipedia has a [list of top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) but few of their entries specify availability or restrictions, such as having to be a citizen or have a business presence, etc.

So, what are some top-level domains with no to little restrictions with regards to who may register? These are domains particularly useful in [domain hacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_hack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia lists them all in the [Country Code top-level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain#List_of_ccTLDs) article, with domains allowing foreign registration marked with an asterisk.

Comment: Somehow I missed that. The problem is it seems inaccurate. `.is` (Iceland) allows foreign registration, yet is not marked with an asterisk.

Comment: It's Wikipedia. Edit the article. Add the asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

In the list of ccTLDs in the Wikipedia article you mentioned, each ccTLD has its own Wikipedia page. In the infobox (on the right) for each country’s page, there is a row titled **Registration restrictions** that may be useful to you.

Alternatively, you could check links to country specific registration policies that are mentioned in [this listing](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1)